# Expanding information capacity of Gaussian Channel

Tags: information-theory

I'm currently try to understand a Gaussian Capacity Channel. I found litterature on internet, and some expand the information capacity of a Gaussian Channel as follow:
$$I(X,Y)= h(Y) -h(Y\mid X) = h(Y) - h(X+Z\mid X).$$

Can anyone explain me this expansion? Does it mean that $h(Y\mid X)=h(X+Z\mid X)$?

Comment: Could you please clarify your notation? I suppose $I(\cdot; \cdot)$ is the mutual information, and $h(\cdot)$ is the Shannon entropy, right? Also, what are $X$, $Y$ and $Z$?

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the channel output $Y$ is the sum of the channel input $X$ and the noise $Z$, i.e. $Y=X+Z$.